# Using TCL to capture SYSlog (port 514) UDP/TCP?

Tags: tcl, syslog

I'm looking for the best way to capture network generated syslog on port 514 to a TCL variable list (using something like `lappend mysyslist $newsyslogentry`), or just append to a file (i.e., `open "syslog.txt" a`)

I suspect it would need to be triggered via an event with every new (port 514) entry (i.e., `fileevent $$ readable...`) and if possible allow other programs to access the syslog port?

I believe network syslog traffic is UDP based (not 100% sure), but I've seed UDP + TCP syslog capture apps around.

There are a few SYSlog client apps available, but I need a simple port 514 recorder in TCL.

I have some ideas but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for not just watching the files that the standard syslog writes to? (Also, Tcl needs an extension package to talk UDP at all. There have been proposals to change this, but none have made it to implementation yet for various reasons.)

Comment: Thats the current method of access, but I need to include syslog'ing via my TCL script (for portability) since the clients will have no syslog'ing and all syslog data comes from the modem/router via port 514. Is there such a thing as TCP syslog data or is it just UDP? (UDP makes more sense on a broadcast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, I've created a UDP version here:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh
package require udp ; # load the required UDP Package

set port 514 ; # default SYSlog port
set logfile "udp_syslog.txt" ; # set the log filename to log data to

# Capture the UDP data here
proc udp_triggered {} {
    global dg logfile ; # ensure the global variables work in this procedure
    set rcdata [read $dg(udp)] ; # grab the UDP data within rcdata
    set udp_log [open $logfile a] ; # open the specified logfile to append to (auto-creates if does not exist)
    puts $udp_log $rcdata ; # place the UDP data line into the log file
    close $udp_log ; # close the log file
    return
}

set dg(udp) [udp_open $port] ; # setup the UDP capture port
fileevent $dg(udp) readable udp_triggered ; # setup the event trigger when the UDP port becomes readable and execute the procedure to capture the data
vwait forever ; # activates the (fileevent) trigger to wait for UDP data
```